# Fastest way to add to and get values from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm just getting started with JavaScript objects. I'm trying to store catalog inventory by id and locations. I think a single object would look something like this:

```
var item = {
    id: number,
    locations: ["location1", "location2"]
 };
```

I've started to read a bit about it but am still trying to wrap my head around it. Not sure what is the fastest way add new items to a list with a location, add a new location to an existing item, all while checking for dupes. Performance of getting the locations later isn't as critical. This is part of a process that is running thousands of checks to eventually get items by id and location, so performance is key.

Final question, I'm not even sure if it's possible to store this in local storage. From another similar question, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), something like this should work to determine if an item id exists and append either a new item to the array, or just add a new location:

```
var item = [{
        id: 1,
        locations: ["location1", "location2"]
     },{
        id: 2,
         locations: ["location2", "location4"]
     }];

    function findItem(id){
        return _.findIndex(item, function(chr) {
            return chr.id == id;
        });
    }
    function addItem(id,locations) {
        var position = findItem(id);
        if (position<0) {
            item.push({
                id: id,
                locations: locations
            })
        } else { 
            item[position].locations = _.uniq(item[position].locations.concat(locations));
        }
    }

    addItem(2,['location292']);
    addItem(3,['location23']);
    console.log(item);
```

What it basically does is to search the array of objects (item) for an id as the one we are passing to the `addItem()` function, if it is found we add the new locations array to the existing item, if not it's creating a new object with a new id and location.

Comment: Wonderful @michael. This looks great. I tried an example and the results are undefined. Trying to figure it out now.

    addItem(id, [location]);
    var singleItem = findItem(id);
    if (singleItem.length) {
        console.log('Item: [' + id + '] ' + singleItem.locations.join(', '));
    }

Comment: You don't need to check anything, the functions do that all for you @empedocle

Comment: I see the addItem is working great. FindItem isn't returning anything though the code looks ok to me.

Comment: `findItem()` returns the index of the object inside the array and -1 if it's not in it, that might be why it looks like it doesn't return.

Comment: Have a look here, that might explain it http://jsfiddle.net/bebjd4k9/1/ @empedocle

Comment: Got it. was experimenting while your were posting. addItem doesn't check for dupes. Not sure if it would be faster to run a find item first to see if it's stored, or there's some other method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88336/discussion-between-empedocle-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a question that contains some tradeoffs:

1. The simplest and fastest way to retrieve a list of locations is to store them in an array.
2. The fastest way to check something for a duplicates is not an array, but rather a `map` object that maintains an index of the key.

So, you'd have to discuss more about which set of tradeoffs you want.  Do you want to optimize for performance of adding a non-duplicate or optimize for performance of retrieving the list of locations.  Pick one or the other.

As for localStorage, you can store any string in LocalStorage and you can convert simply non-reference objects to a string with `JSON.stringify()`, so yes this type of structure can be stored in LocalStorage.

For example, if you want to use the array for optimized retrieval, then you can check for duplicates like this before adding:

```
function addLocation(item, newLocation) {
    if (item.locations.indexOf(newLocation) === -1) {
        item.locations.push(newLocation);
    }
}
```

---

Also, you can store an array of items in LocalStorage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("someKey", JSON.stringify(arrayOfItems));
```

And, then some time later, you can retrieve it like this:

```
var arrayOfItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("someKey"));
```

Comment: Retrieval performance isn't as critical. I use local storage at the moment though your example seems to store each item separately. I was looking to store an array of objects, though I wasn't sure if array of objects, or merely object, is the proper term.

Comment: @empedocle - if your question is about storing a list of objects, then please show that in your question (you only show a single item and refer to store "this".  It doesn't say anything about an array of locations in the question.  So, if you have an array of `item` objects, then call `JSON.stirngify()` on that array.  No different in concept.

Comment: @jfrield00 Yes it would be a list of objects. Question updated. I wasn't sure if stringify worked on more than simple arrays but good to know.